# DIfficulty determining what 'this' refers to in JS/jQuery code

Tags: javascript, jquery, this, asynccallback

I'm experiencing difficulty figuring out what 'this' refers to, in multiple instances of the following code:

```
 jQuery(function ($) {

    var coreChat = {

      fetch: function (fn) {
        $.ajax({
          url: "https://api.parse.com/1/classes/chats",
          data: {
             order: 'createdAt',
             limit: 10
          },
          type: "GET"
        })
        .done(function(data) {
          var messages = [];
          for (var i = 0, len = data.results.length; i < len; i++) {
            messages.push(data.results[i].text);
          }

          return fn(messages);
        });
      },

      send: function (message) {
        var data = JSON.stringify({text: message});
        $.ajax({
          url: "https://api.parse.com/1/classes/chats",
          data: data,
          type: "POST"
        });
      },

      display: function (messages) {

        // http://jsperf.com/update-only-text-vs-remove-dom

        var messageNode = $(".messages").find("li");

        messageNode.each(function (i) {
          var $this = $(this);
          if ($this.text() !== messages[i]) {
            $this.text(messages[i]);
          }
        });

      }

    };


    var myChat = {

      init: function () {
        **this**.fetchInitialData();
        **this**.bindSendEvent();
        **this**.refresh();
      },

      fetchInitialData: function () {
        var messagesWrapper = $(".messages");
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
          $("<li></li>").appendTo(messagesWrapper);
        }
        myChat.updateMessages();
      },

      bindSendEvent: function () {
        $(".send").on("click", function (e) {
          var input = $(".draft");
          myChat.send(Chat.username + ": " + input.val());
          input.val("");
          e.preventDefault();
        });
      },

      refresh: function () {
        setInterval(function () {
          myChat.updateMessages();
        }, 3000);
      },

      updateMessages: function () {
        this.fetch(function (messages) {
          myChat.display(messages);
        });
      }

    };

    $.extend(myChat, coreChat);
    myChat.init();

  });
```

More specifically, in the bottom half of the code - in the myChat object, there is an "init" property which, as a value, contains a function...

```
var myChat = {

      init: function () {
        this.fetchInitialData();
        this.bindSendEvent();
        this.refresh();
      },
```

What would 'this' be referring to here? And does the fact that coreChat was extended into myChat on the 2nd to last line of the code make a difference in determining what 'this' refers to?

```
$.extend(myChat, coreChat);
```

Also, there's another 'this' in the updateMessages property of the myChat object...

```
updateMessages: function () {
        this.fetch(function (messages) {
          myChat.display(messages);
        });
      }
```

^ What does this refer to in this instance? The fetch function from coreChat is being executed on 'this', but again, what is 'this'?

And as a quick tangential question - in the updateMessages function, it calls the 'fetch' function.'fetch' is asynchronous with a callback function ('fetch' is originally found in the coreChat object). But then in updateMessages, what is that function that is passed in as a parameter to fetch? Is fetch supposed to execute it's original callback function, and then this parameter is to act as the parameter of the callback? I'm definitely confused there.

^ I understand that's 2 separate questions - I'll delete it if that poses an issue, and post it in a new separate question, but I just thought, since someone may have already gone thru the entire code, maybe he'd/she'd already be equipped to answer the 2nd question and I might as well ask...

THANKS IN Advance!

Comment: `this` is `myChat` because `myChat.init()`. `this` depends on how the function gets called.

Comment: Ahhh i see... What about in the updateMessages portion of the code?

Comment: [This page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) is, in one expressive word: *awesome*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, "this" is pretty much always referring to the myChat object.

If you were to call init you would write `myChat.init()`. init is part of the myChat object, so `this` refers to the containing object. Init is specified within the scope of myChat, as are all of your other functions, meaning that this function and all others are part of `myChat`, and therefore `this` is `myChat`

```
var myChat = {

      init: function () {
        this.fetchInitialData();
        this.bindSendEvent();
        this.refresh();
      },
      ...
}
```

Also, if you look at the jquery documentation on extend (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/), the description is "Merge the contents of two or more objects together into the first object.". So when you `$.extend(myChat, coreChat);`, what you're actually doing is copying all properties from `coreChat` into the `myChat` object. So, when you call fetch in this code, you're actually calling the fetch method that has been copied into your `myChat` object, so `this` also still refers to `myChat`. To further reinforce that these methods were added to the myChat object, notice you're calling `myChat.display`? That was defined in `coreChat`, but you're accessing it using `myChat` instead.

```
updateMessages: function () {
        this.fetch(function (messages) {
          myChat.display(messages);
        });
      }
```

There is an instance where `this` does not refer to `myChat`. That is in the display function of `coreChat`. Since you're using the jquery .each function, within the scope of that function, `this` refers to the list item that the function is being run on, and NOT the `coreChat` object (or more precisely the `myChat` copy of this `coreChat` function as explained above).

```
var messageNode = $(".messages").find("li");
messageNode.each(function (i) {
          var $this = $(this);
          if ($this.text() !== messages[i]) {
            $this.text(messages[i]);
          }
        });
```

**As for part 2 of your question:**

The function that is passed as a parameter to `fetch` is a callback function for when `fetch` is completed. The definition for `fetch` includes a function as a parameter:

```
fetch: function (fn) {
```

In the `.done` function, the callback function is invoked, passing in the message data, and returning the result of that callback:

```
return fn(messages);
```

So, you call `.fetch` and pass in your function, `fetch` executes and does all of its processing, and then `fetch` calls your passed-in function.

Comment: As a sort of follow up question - why would one create 2 different objects and then use the extend function? Or at least in this case, what do you think the advantages were to doing it this way as opposed to creating 1 all-encompassing object from the start? @Joel

Comment: @Seeeyonnn $.extend is really acting as a way to obtain some sort of class inheritance behavior since this doesn't exist in javascript. By separating out the two objects and extending one, you can essentially create different chats with the same core functionality. In this case, the advantage is mostly separating out the data logic from the display logic. This is true even though the core object contains some display logic because you can always override the display function within your new object.

Answer (score 2):

If you are coming from an object-oriented world such as Java, 'this' is a bit of a different concept.  In languages, like Java, 'this' refers to the currently executing object and is defined by how the method is declared.  But, in Javascript, 'this' refers to how the function was *invoked* and is really the execution context of the function.  In fact, to quote John Resig in 'Secrets of the Javascript Ninja', it should really be called the invocation context.

To answer your questions:

1. `this` in the `init` function is referring to the `myChat` object.  No, the fact that you used jQuery.extend to merge the two objects has no bearing on the value of this.  That is a bit misleading on jQuery's part.
2. `this` in `updateMessages` also refers to the `myChat` object

One thing to be wary of in your above code is the `setInterval` portion in `refresh`.  Your code is correct since it invokes the function on the `myChat` object explicitly, but in that function, `this` refers to the global object (most likely '`window`' if you're running in a browser).

Finally, to answer your third question regarding the callback, `fetch` runs an asynchronous  POST.  When that POST completes, the `done` callback is called.  The value returned from that `done` callback is the value of invoking the function passed to `fetch`.  In your example, that looks to be `undefined` since your function calls `display` but `display` doesn't specify a return value.  Any function that doesn't specify a return will return `undefined` by default.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

`this` in JavaScript depends on how the function itself is used. It changes depending on the parent object, bind/apply/call invocations, if it's used with a constructor, etc.. check out [this on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) for all the gory details.